# Typeorm migrations: there is no unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have many to one relation with typeorm constructed like this:

In **PostEntity** Class

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;
@ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.posts)
userPosted: UserEntity;
```

In **UserEntity** Class

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;
@OneToMany(type => PostEntity, c => c.userPosted)
posts: PostEntity[];
```

I can succesfully create migrations but when I tried to run it throws error:

> query failed: ALTER TABLE "post" ADD CONSTRAINT
>   "FK_f36f38b0231a9075541aae12b73" FOREIGN KEY ("user_posted_id")
>   REFERENCES "user"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION error:
>   { error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "user"

I just followed docs. Don't know why migrations won't update in database.
Migrations file: https://gist.github.com/DooMachine/fe6a34817ed763941d74097acd4a4efd

Comment: can you enable debug mode and post what queries typeorm is trying to make? [This seems to be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473880/error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-referenced-table-u) save for the fact that it is not typeorm specific

Comment: ok, let me create a gist: https://gist.github.com/DooMachine/fe6a34817ed763941d74097acd4a4efd
check for lines: 8 and 15 are post and user table creation and line 37 is where the error comes from.